# Convert JsonFactory object into a stringified JSON field in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The posts I've seen are reversed but I need to create a JSON string from an object. I'm brand new to Kotlin but in JS I'm essentially looking for `stringify`.

For example:

```
JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'})
```

That output is what I want.

I built an object like this (which, if this is wrong it doesn't need to be built this way, I'm just trying to figure this out)

```
    val factory = JsonFactory()
    val generator = factory.createGenerator(output, JsonEncoding.UTF8)

    generator.writeStartObject()
        generator.writeNumberField("statusCode", 200)

        generator.writeObjectFieldStart("body") // The value inside specifically needs to be a JSON string!
            generator.writeStringField("userId", user.id.toString())
            generator.writeStringField("amount", user.amount.toString())
            generator.writeStringField("percent", user.percent.toString())
        generator.writeEndObject()

    generator.writeEndObject()

    generator.close()
```

This will create an object like:

```
{"statusCode": 200, body: {userId: ..., amount: ..., percent: ...}}
```

However, this won't work (working with a Lambda + API Gateway) and the body needs to be a stringified JSON blob like this:

```
{"statusCode": 200, body: "{\"userId\": ..., \"amount:\" ..., \"percent:\" ...}"}
```

I'm just not sure how to do it. Currently (so I can get something to work) I'm just concat'ing in a stringField like:

```
generator.writeStringField("body", "{" +
```

Which is very gross and hard to manage so I'd like to do it the "right" way and I have a feeling there's an easy way to do this but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

`kotlinx.serialization` provides solution for that:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@UseExperimental(ImplicitReflectionSerializer::class)
fun main() {
    val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Default)
    println(json.stringify(Response(status = 200,
            body = json.stringify(Payment("abc", 100, 20)))))
}

@Serializable
data class Payment(val userId: String, val amount: Int, val percent: Int)

@Serializable
data class Response(val status: Int, val body: String)
```

But let's say you cannot use `kotlinx.serialization`, since it's experimental.

You can still use `ObjectMapper` from `jackson` library (as I see you're using their `JsonFactory`, which is low level):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

fun main() {
    val json = ObjectMapper()

    println(json.writeValueAsString(Response(status = 200,
            body = json.writeValueAsString(Payment("abc", 100, 20)))))
}

data class Payment(val userId: String, val amount: Int, val percent: Int)

data class Response(val status: Int, val body: String)
```

You can even have your own `JSON.stringify`:

```
object JSON {
    fun stringify(e: Any) = ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(e)
}
```

Or have it as an extension function:

```
fun main() {
    println(Response(status = 200,
            body = Payment("abc", 100, 20).asJson().toString()).asJson())
}

data class Payment(val userId: String, val amount: Int, val percent: Int)

data class Response(val status: Int, val body: String)

fun Any.asJson() = ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this)
```